# CSS: Conflict between position and align

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

I would like to show a H1 header in the center of page and also set its position as "fixed"(since I don't want it to go away from screen when user scrolls)

I've tried the following options, but unfortunately couldn't achieve it.

Option 1:

```
<div align="center" style="position:fixed;"><h1>Welcome</h1></div>
```

Option 2:

```
<h1 text-align="center" style="position:fixed;">Welcome</h1>
```

Option 3:

```
<h1 text-align="center" position="fixed">Welcome</h1>
```

So far, all of the above options shows the text in fixed position, but it's not in the center of screen. But when I remove the `position: fixed;`, the text appears in center of screen.

Any suggestions?

Comment: used to left , right and top property with position fixed ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 <div  align="center" style="position:fixed;width:100%"><h1>Welcome</h1></div>
```

Give `width:100%` to your `div`.
Here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4v6rcm33/)

Comment: wow, it works... thank you so much :) By the way what is the cause for the conflict?

Comment: Actually it was getting aligned to the center but since your `div's width` was not specified, you were not able to view that. Try inspecting your `div` without changing its `width`. You will see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can define to your div `left:0;` and `right:0;`

**as like this**

```html
<div  align="center" style="position:fixed;left:0;right:0;"><h1>Welcome</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Option 1: <div align="center" style="position:fixed;"><h1>Welcome</h1></div>
```

HTML `align` is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2).

Solutions:

```html
<div style="position:fixed;width:100%;text-align:center;"><h1>Welcome</h1></div>
```

```html
<div style="position:fixed;right:0;left:0;text-align:center;"><h1>Welcome</h1></div>
```

```
Option 2: <h1 text-align="center" style="position:fixed;">Welcome</h1>
```

There is no a HTML attribute which is called `text-align="center"`.

```html
<h1 style="position:fixed;width:100%;text-align:center;">Welcome</h1>
```

```html
<h1 style="position:fixed;left:0;right:0;text-align:center;">Welcome</h1>
```

```
Option 3: <h1 text-align="center" position="fixed">Welcome</h1>
```

HTML attribute does not have `text-align="center"` and `position="fixed"`.

Option 3 solution is like option 2's answers.